# Forms app to prove I can authenticate using NTLM

Tags: winforms, authentication, ntlm

Is it possible to develop a basic client/server Forms app (suppose I could develop the server side as a service, but would rather not) that can prove that a user account within a 2012 R2 Active Directory domain can authenticate with an application residing on a server on a trusted 2003 domain, using **NTLM**? If so, what specifically within my application would I need to do to force such a behaviour?

The detail:

I am responsible for performing an upgrade of Active Directory from 2003 to 2012 R2 (raising of the Forest and Domain Functional Level). There is a legacy application which does not support Kerberos authentication and a lot of doubt that this mission critical application will still work after the domain upgrade. To complicate the matter, the user accounts are in the domain to be upgraded and the application backend is hosted on a trusted domain that will not be upgraded.

I am required to first of all test the process and outcome within a test lab (replica of the live environment). I am unable to replicate the application as it is to big and complicated to do so. One of the tests I need to satisfy is to verify that a user can be authenticated by a trusted domain using NTLM (not Kerberos).

Comment: For better or for worse NTLM works just fine all the way up through 2019.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can use the age old DOS "NET USE" command to verify NTLM authentication. "NET" only uses NTLM :)